# "The RSA key contained could not be opened" on all 32 bit Windows systems

Tags: c#, encryption, vsto, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have an Outlook VSTO Add-In with an encrypted app.config. I did it using this command :

> cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
>
> ASPNET_REGIIS -pef "connectionStrings" "path"

I did that on a 64 bit Windows machine. Now when I use my Add-In on any 32 bit Windows devices and attempt to use controls that read or edit app.config I get this error -

> "The RSA key contained could not be opened"

Most solutions I found suggest providing access to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys to all the users. That didn't work for me though. Someone also suggested encrypting the file on a 32 bit system but wouldn't that cause the same problem to occur on 64 bit? I feel like I'm missing something here, could it be something with the encryption process or is it just something you have to fix afterwards? Any clues will be appreciated.

Here is how my config looks now :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
          <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
          </KeyInfo>
          <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>cipheredvaluehere</CipherValue>
          </CipherData>
        </EncryptedKey>
      </KeyInfo>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>cipheredvaluehere</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: So you export and copy key with which you encrypted your connection strings to other machines?

Comment: What I did exactly was publish the project, rename projectname.dll.config.deploy to web.config, encrypt web.config with the command, rename web.config back to projectname.dll.config.deploy, then copied the contents of the encrypted config and pasted it into the project in visual studio and published it again. Then I gave it to another machine. Is this not how you're supposed to do this if your config contains connection strings? It worked well on all 64 bit systems I tested so far.

Comment: I edited the thread to provide how my config looks like now.

Comment: That's strange, if you didn't copy key to that other machine I wonder how it can decrypt your configuration even on 64bit machines.

Comment: Isn't key info under the links (in config, see edit) that noone but the decryption service has access to?

Comment: You encrypt with some key (information about which key is contained in `KeyInfo`, but not the key itself), and that key is stored as file on your filesystem (in %ProgramData%\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys). So to decrypt you need the same key (file) on another machine.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here. Should I include that file in my ClickOnce instalator? Wouldn't that make it easy for people to decrypt the config?

Comment: Well I don't know. You claim that it already works on 64bit machines (other than machine on which you created that addin of course) somehow and if so - key is not a problem.

Comment: Okay so this made me curious and I uninstalled my project from the machines it worked on. I must've accidentally used an older install that didn't have encrypted config yet, wow. Can't believe I missed that. It doesn't work anywhere but on my machine now. Sorry for the confusion. Guess the key is the reason then.

Comment: Note that encrypting your config and then publish key with which you encrypted it together with application does not make much sense anyway.

Comment: That was my first thought when I heard that I should share the key too. I hoped it was somehow acquired from the links in the config so I don't have to bother. So what is the proper way of encrypting my config then if reg iis decryption requires an accessible key from user machine?

Comment: Any type of encryption requires key to decrypt to be accessible somehow, be it file or stored in memory, or requested from remote service. Why are you going to encrypt it in the first place? To protect from what?

Comment: I know about the basic principals of encrypting. I was just hoping in this case this was done via some web service so user wouldn't have direct access to the key but the process would, I don't know. My product checks if a key provided by the user is valid on product activation. Keys are stored in a database but I don't want the user to be able to view all of them, which he would be able to do if he had access to the connection string.

Comment: If you modified the ACLs on the `MachineKeys` directory, revert them immediately. Non-privileged users should not be able to directly access that directly; allowing access may leak all private keys to any user that is authenticated to the box.

Comment: Could you provide some more insight into how those can be leaked?